# How do I resize a table and its cells as screen size shrinks?

Tags: html, css

https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/#

I'm using a similar table layout like the one linked for a project I'm currently doing but I can't seem to figure out how to not have the cells wrap onto a new row when the screen size shrinks. How is it done in this Pathfinding Visualizer project? What CSS property should I be applying to my table/tr/td? When I shrink my screen size, my table's cells wrap onto the next row making it so that every other row has a different number of columns. I'd like for the table width and, consequently, the table cells to just shrink in width and have the same columns in every row even for smaller screen sizes.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;

}

.grid-row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually provided a link to your table or it's code.

But, if you're actually using a table structure, your white-space: nowrap; call should be applied to your td elements and not your tr elements.

Again, without a link to your table it's difficult to answer. But perhaps this will point you in the right direction?